# find row number in matlab

Tags: matlab

From the following example:

```
x = 1 + (10-1)*rand(1,100);
x(12:22) = 20 + (30-20)*rand(1,11);
x(70:94) = 20 + (30-20)*rand(1,25);
```

Here I am attempting a couple of things. Firstly I am trying to find the row number for the first value that is greater than 20 where the number of successive values >20 is more than 24.  So in this example I would like to return the row number 70.

I can do this by:

```
y = x > 20;
k = [strfind([~y(1),y],[0 1]);strfind([y,~y(end)],[1 0])];
idx = k(1,diff(k) + 1 > 24);
```

However, I would also like to replace the first set of values (which did not include more than 24 successive values > 20) to nan. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your line `k = [strfind([~y(1),y],[0 1]);strfind([y,~y(end)],[1 0])];` is giving a horzcat error.

Comment: please view amended question. The vectors needed to be transposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a fine solution for finding `idx`, maybe find is better suited, I don't know:

```
y = x > 20;
kstart = find(diff([0 y])==1);
kend   = find(diff([y 0])==-1);
klen   = kend-kstart+1;

idx = kstart(find(klen>=24,1,'first')); %*
```

<sub><sub>*yes, I know you can omit `'first'`, but it's there for clarity.</sub></sub>

Anyway: to replace the first set of values (those who have `index<idx`) use:

```
x(1:idx-1) = NaN;
```

Or if you meant to only replace all the numbers larger than 20 before `idx`:

```
x(y(1:idx-1)) = NaN;
```

Comment: Why `1:idx-1`? Shouldn't it be `kstart(idx):kend(idx)` like the OP wants?

Comment: @EitanT `kstart(idx):kend(idx)` wouldn't make any sense, since `idx` is an index to the original data vector, whilst `kstart` and `kend` are also indices to the original vector.. I read OP's question as: set the whole set of values (in the beginning of the vector) which do not contain 24 consecutive numbers larger than 20, to `NaN`, see my edit for another interpretation...

Comment: For some reason I thought `idx` was the result of `find`, but now I see it's a subset of `kstart`. In any case, I believe the OP wanted to replace the first sequence of x>20 _that is not longer than 24_ to `NaN`, so based on this your answer is still flawed even though being accepted...

Comment: @EitanT It still depends on how you define a `set`; in OP's example there was only one consecutive series before `idx`, so yeah, no difference there. And imo my answer is what OP intended... certainly because the question would be trivial otherwise, since she already had the start and end points of the series `x>20` in the variable `k`

Comment: If it's trivial because the start and end are known, then the answer for your interpretation is also trivial. Maybe I'm just over-analyzing it, IDK. In any case, your answer deserves +1.

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part of your question, here's a one-liner for finding *all* the indices of 25 or more successive occurrences of elements greater than 20:

```
idx = strfind((x(:)' > 20), ones(1, 25));
```

Use `idx(1)` to obtain the first index, which is 70 in your example.

As for the second part of your question, here's a solution:

```
idx_start = strfind([0, x(:)'] > 20, [0 1]);           %# Start indices
len = strfind([x(:)' > 20, 0], [1 0]) - idx_start + 1; %# Sequence lengths
first = find(len < 25, 1);                             %# First desired sequence
x(idx_start(first):idx_start(first) + len(first) - 1) = NaN;
```

Note that this replaces only the *first* successive occurences of x > 20, which are no more than 24.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to the set of already good solutions.

You could use a convolution as well:

```
tmp = conv(x>20, ones(1,25));
inds = find(tmp==25)
first_indes = inds(1);
```